# How to define an async client for the whole class?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, binance, binance-api-client

Hi I can define async client object only one time - one connection to server and then working with it, but I coudn't undestand how to define this client global for class. I just guessed to create a new connection before each use, but of course that wastes extra time. Will be glad for any offers. Library: https://pypi.org/project/python-binance/

Working code:

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient

class Binance:
    async def get_trades(self):
        client = await AsyncClient.create() # define two times(two connections) need only one
        aggregate_trades = await client.get_all_tickers()
        print(aggregate_trades)
        await client.close_connection()

    async def exchange_info(self):
        client = await AsyncClient.create() # define two times(two connections) need only one
        exchange_info = await client.get_exchange_info()
        print(exchange_info)
        await client.close_connection()

async def main():
    b = Binance()
    await asyncio.gather(b.get_trades(), b.exchange_info())
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Should be(but not working):

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient

class Binance:
    def __init__(self):
        asyncio.run(self.async_init())

    async def async_init(self):
        self.client = await AsyncClient.create() # define only one time because use much time

    async def get_trades(self):
        aggregate_trades = await self.client.get_all_tickers()
        print(aggregate_trades)

    async def exchange_info(self):
        exchange_info = await self.client.get_exchange_info()
        print(exchange_info)

async def main():
    b = Binance()
    await asyncio.gather(b.get_trades(), b.exchange_info())
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

UPD: Error:
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Binance.async_init' was never awaited

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error? Is the behavior different than you expected? Please update the question with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

asyncio doesn't support moving from asynchronous code to synchronous code back to asynchronous code. That is why you're getting

`RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

There are a couple of ways you can address this. You can call `async_init` externally

```
async def main():
    b = Binance()
    await b.async_init()
```

Depending on how much work actually needs to be done by `async_init`, this could be the simplest approach. The other option is to provide the client yourself

```
class Binance:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    b = Binance(client=client)
```

If you don't have too many things to pass in, I like this approach better. It makes `client` reusable outside of the `Binance` instance and it can often make it easier to test the `Binance` class by providing a fake client instance.